# Random number generation with in a range

Tags: random

Suppose all I have is a routine that generates 0 and 1 randomly with equal probability , how can I use this to find a random number between 1 and n .I can't use any other random function. I need to use my routine to achieve the goal.Please any pointers will he helpful.

Comment: call your function n times and just sum

Comment: @MujahidDaudKhan Except that won't give a uniform distribution, which I expect the asker wants.

Comment: what language are we talking about here?

Comment: @TimothyShields Yes, You are right

Comment: @Mujahid Daud Khan: Your algorithm's outcome is binomial distribution, not uniform one

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks for info, i am not good in probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Let m = ceil(log<sub>2</sub>(n)); that is, m is the number of bits needed to represent n.
2. Generate a random bitstring of length m, and interpret it as a nonnegative integer k.
3. If k >= n, go back to step 2. Otherwise your random number is k + 1.

This is a form of rejection sampling that will give you a uniform distribution on the random integer k + 1 in the range [1, n].

Answer (score 0):

Simplely use the fomular 
   rand()*(n-1)+1

Comment: Sorry, but since random() is either 0 or 1, the outcome will be either 1 or n, without any intermediate values